# Unwanted referencing behaviour with Biber: "In:" appears when no journal is specified

Tags: bibliographies

My MWE comprises two files, main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

I am citing this source \cite{Lamont:1997755}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and references.bib:

```
@article{Lamont:1997755,
      author        = "Lamont, Mike and O'Luanaigh, Cian",
      title         = "{LHC report: Run 1 -- the final flurry}",
      month         = "Feb",
      year          = "2013",
      url           = "http://cds.cern.ch/record/1997755",
}
```

My compile procedure is simply:

```
rm -f *aux *bbl *log *toc

pdflatex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex
biber main
pdflatex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex
```

My question is this: when I compile this, I see in the bibliography the following formatting:

Mike Lamont and Cian O’Luanaigh. “LHC report: Run 1 – the final
flurry”. In: (Feb. 2013). url: http://cds.cern.ch/record/1997755.

I don't want the "In:" to appear if there is no `journal =` field in the reference. Does anyone know how to alter the reference style to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `@Online` entry type  (I had to rename the `.bib` file to prevent any interference with personal files):

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

 \usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{unwantedIn.bib}

\begin{document}

I am citing this source \cite{Lamont:1997755}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Bib file:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Online{Lamont:1997755,
  author = {Lamont, Mike and O'Luanaigh, Cian},
  title  = {LHC report: Run 1 -- the final flurry},
  year   = {2013},
  month  = {2},
  url    = {http://cds.cern.ch/record/1997755},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

[image]